# Checkbox inside context menu not displays correctly wp7

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, checkbox, contextmenu

I have a context menu and checkbox inside it, but checkbox displays not correctly.

```
                    <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                      <toolkit:ContextMenu >
                        <toolkit:MenuItem Click="iLikeIt" Tag="{Binding ElementName=chbox}"  Header="{Binding isLikeMe, Converter={StaticResource LikeIt}}"/>
                        <toolkit:MenuItem>
                          <toolkit:MenuItem.Header>
                            <CheckBox Name="chbox" Tag="{Binding}" BorderThickness="1" Content="Рассказать друзьям" >
                            </CheckBox>
                          </toolkit:MenuItem.Header>
                        </toolkit:MenuItem>
                      </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
```

[image]

Comment: I've never seen anyone stuff a `Checkbox` inside the `ContextMenu`; it may not be possible. Have you tried using a `Popup` instead?

Comment: Checkbox is working very well excluding ui.
hmm..if I will use Popup with GestureListener it may be good idea, but what's with performance?

Comment: AFAIK the `ContextMenu` is a `Popup` :-) So performance should be the same.

Comment: Could this be a styling issue due to the fact the CheckBox's style in the dark theme would be to appear as white, but the ContextMenu has reversed the background colour so it not visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a UI issue and not a functional one this is very likely a styling issue with the CheckBox. You will need to apply a custom style to the CheckBox in the ContextMenu so that it looks OK in the inverted colours of the ContextMenu.

Make sure you make it work in both Dark and Light theme though.